# Linq generate select with no from

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

In sql I can do this

```
select 'a' as MyColumn
```

so, i have a query in linq with entity framework that get some data from the database, but, i need union that query with one row, and in sql I can do this:

```
select ... from ...
union 
select 'a' as MyColumn
```

How can i generate this query with linq?
I tried to do this:

```
var query = (from ... select new {..}).Union(new List<...> { new ...() { MyColumn = 'a' } })
```

But i gess that Entity Framework DON'T know how to translate that in memory list to sql

I need to get an IQueryable result, not a List or other in memory Collection, because i need to join that result to other sql linq querys in the future.

Comment: You should be able to do it. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852442/linq-union-with-constant-values).

Comment: @RigertaDemiri, the problem with that aproach is that they get the first query to a List<> in memory, THEN adds a element to that list. I need to keep the IQueryable, not in memory. Maybe, i did'nt say it in the question. I will update it.

Comment: Does `Enumerable.Repeat(new { MyColumn = 'a' }, 1)` work for you?

Comment: @Enigmativity, i will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible and you shouldn't do it. Both for the same reason: Entity Framework will try to translate the whole LINQ statement into SQL, including the local list (`new List<...>`).

The reason why it's not possible is that EF has no way to translate C# objects into SQL constructs.

The reason why you shouldn't do it is that it's incredibly wasteful: you build the list in C# code, EF (if it could) translates it into a SQL statement, the database runs the SQL statement and converts it to a result set, EF receives the result set and converts it into the list you originally offered it.

Just to demonstrate it, I'll show what happens if you do this with a list of primitive values which EF does know how to translate into SQL:

```
var ints = Enumerable.Range(1,5);
var res = Products.Select(c => c.Id).Union(ints).ToList();
```

This produces the following SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
        [UnionAll5].[ProductId] AS [C1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId]
            FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent1]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            2 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            3 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            4 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable4]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            5 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable5]) AS [UnionAll5]
    )  AS [Distinct1]
```

As you see, for each element in the list EF generated a `SingleRowTable`x entry to build a "temp table" to UNION with the ids from the actual query.

Conclusion: just query what you need from the database and add to the result afterwards. It's easy enough to do that:

```
(from ... select new {..})
    .AsEnumerable() // continue in memory
    .Union(...)
```

Comment: I should mention that EF-core will automatically switch to client-side evaluation in this case, that is, it will run the `Union` in client (C#) code. I assumed you work in EF6, because that still seems to be the "default" when only [entity-framework] is tagged.

Comment: That is exactly what i need, even when entity framework creates that select with unions.